# How to get response from https url using curl and shell script

Tags: shell, curl

I have written a unix script using curl that returns the response headers of the http url.However i would like to do the same for https and i am unable to do so.I need these to check if the sites are up and running or not.

My code for http sites

```
status=$(curl -s --head  -w %{http_code} http://10.196.56.112:9081/ -o /dev/null)
echo $status

if [ "$status" == "000" ];
then echo "Server down"

else
echo "Server up"
fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works exactly the same way for HTTPS.

The only little difference is that HTTPS implies that curl will verify the TLS certificate of the server and unless you use `--insecure` curl will exit with an error if it can't verify it successfully. In your example here, you use an IP address and not a name and that will most certainly cause a certificate check to fail.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.. It did work !!! Cheers.
However could you help me in depth regarding why curl will exit with an error?

Comment: If you have another question, file another question!

Comment: I have a dynamic DNS configured at my end so will it skip the certificate check when the final address is resolved?

Comment: curl only skips the check if you use -k / --insecure

Comment: Is there a way to set a time limit that the curl waits for the header response?As i do not want my entire script to wait for a long time just because a single URL is in hung state.

Comment: I'd suggest the -m option for that, or a -Y/-y combo you think is fair.

Comment: What is the default time it will wait for -m option ?is it customizable..? and how is -Y/-y combo different from the above?